# What is the relation between @RequestMapping and Locale in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, annotations

If my understanding is correct, you can add/remove params for saveEmployee() freely. For example, when you add "loc" as follows, saveEmployee() receives the "non-null object" when the event happens.  And the same goes for queryParams.

```java
@Controller
public class Employee {
  @RequestMapping("/save")
  public void saveEmployee(Locale loc, 
                           @RequestParam Map<String, String> queryParams) {
    // saving employee
  }
}
```

How could this method receive non-null Locale object by just adding a param "loc" here?
I would like to know the logic behind this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring does it for you by using `LocaleResolver` or `LocaleContextResolver`, **for the current request locale, determined by the most specific locale resolver available, in effect, the configured `LocaleResolver / LocaleContextResolver` in an MVC environment.**

[21.3.3 Defining @RequestMapping handler methods](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-methods)

> **An @RequestMapping handler method can have a very flexible signatures. The supported method arguments and return values are described in the following section.** Most arguments can be used in arbitrary order with the only exception of BindingResult arguments.

[Supported method argument types](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-arguments)

> java.util.Locale for the current request locale, determined by the most specific locale resolver available, in effect, the configured LocaleResolver / LocaleContextResolver in an MVC environment.

Answer (score 0):

Spring's DispatcherServlet which forwards request from client to your controller gives you that parameters. In order to do that, it search the object from ApplicationContext to which bean(Controller) belongs.

Answer (score 0):

Spring looks at the method arguments, their types and annotations, then determines if it can provide an object of that type/annotation.

If it cannot, it'll throw an exception, otherwise it will call the method with the object it decided fits the type/annotation.

For the list of supported types/annotations, read the documentation:
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-arguments

As you can see, `java.util.Locale` is listed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you  need xml setting for your locale
 Do you want to try the followning xml setting

```
   <bean id="localeResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
   </bean>
   <mvc:interceptors>
    <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="language" />
    </bean>
   </mvc:interceptors>
```